# Django modular editable tables

Tags: django

http://nextgensim.info/grids
just saw this demo,
I need to create modular editable tables with django, searched the web, even standard modular tables seems to be hard. Does anybody suggest a way to get these kind of tables using django?
it has to be modular and editable.

Let's say I have a Facebook-like page, and user should be able to edit his friends nicknames on a table, and table will update the database.